# Where I can get activation from the metamethods while using function in table like this: tbl.myIndex(myParameters)?

Tags: lua, meta-method

I hope you all can help me. So, I want to know when I call function in table like this which metamethod is activating:

```lua
local myTbl = setmetatable({
     myIndex = function(myParam)
         print(myParam)
     end
}, {
    -- Which is the metamethod that activates itself while using myIndex
})
```

I tried EVERYTHING!!! I mean. I made metatable and I used every single metamethod and nothing is called from the metamethods I used.

Answer (score 0):

If you *remove* `myIndex` from the table, `myTbl.myIndex ()` will activate the `__index` metamethod, which can either be a function `(table, key)` or a table.

`myIndex ()` will only be called if `__index (table, key)` takes care of that, or if there is `__index.myIndex` function doing what you want.

See [13.4.1 – The __index Metamethod](https://www.lua.org/pil/13.4.1.html) from [Programming in Lua](https://www.lua.org/pil/contents.html).

**Update**, after reading comments:
By manipulating metatables and redefining functions you can effectively add new metamethods (e.g., by redefining the globals `pairs()` and `ipairs()` you can enable in Lua 5.1 `__pairs` and `__ipairs` metamethods, introduced in Lua 5.2).

The metatable is usually set in a 'wrapper' function that receives a table and returns its extended / enriched version. Like this:

```lua
local new_metamethod_name = '__method'

local function set_extended_metatable (t, mt)
    local old__index = mt.__index -- remember to emulate later, if any.
    mt.__index = function (table, index)
        if type (mt [new_metamethod_name]) == 'function' and type (t [index]) == 'function' then
            -- invoke the new metamethod for methods only, not properties:
            mt [new_metamethod_name] (table, index)
        end
        return t [index] -- return data from the original table, if any.
            -- emulate mt.__index, if any:
            or type (old__index) == 'function' and old__index (table, index)
            or type (old__index) == 'table' and old__index [index]
    end
    return setmetatable ({}, mt) -- for {}, __index will be always called.
end

local dumb_table = {
    myIndex = function (myParam)
        return ('In myIndex(). myParam is ' .. tostring (myParam))
    end,
    someProperty = 43
}

local smart_table = set_extended_metatable (dumb_table, { __method = function (tbl, key)
    print ('Invoking the new metamethod')
end })

print (smart_table.myIndex (42)) -- __method() called.
print (smart_table.someProperty) -- __method() not called.
```

Comment: I don't thing you understand me. I want to use the inserted parameters while I call index of a table as function like the myIndex but I want to call it like a function ( myIndex(params) ) and I want to know if there's a metamethod which's activating while I use the index as function because the only one I know is __call but __call is using when you call the table as function like myTbl(params) not any of the indexes like myTbl.myIndex(params). That's what I want to know. I hope you understand me now and I appologize if I made mistake in the English because the English isn't my mother language.

Comment: I presumed that you wanted to use `myTbl.myIndex (myParam)` syntax. In that case, as I said, to invoke the metamethod `__index`, `myTbl.myIndex` ought to be `nil`. But after your comment, I no longer presume that I understand your purpose; in partucular, I don't understand why you cannot do whatever you want with `myTbl` in `myIndex()`.

Comment: I want to know if there's metamethod like __call while using an index from table as function. I hope you can understand me like this.

Comment: No, I don't think any such metamethod exists. The closest is `__index`, which will be called if an index is missing from the table. But see the updated answer.